# How to add a jquery ui slider to a PrestaShop module form

Tags: php, module, smarty, prestashop, jquery-ui-slider

I want to add a range slider on configuration page of my PrestaShop module. I've tried to do this using HelperForm class, but I just can't do this, if I write other type, for example 'textarea' or 'checkbox', it works fine, even with not really standard input types like 'color', but 'range' doesn't work

```
<?php
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
    exit;

class icropper extends Module
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'icropper';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = '1.0';
        $this->author = 'AppDev';
        $this->need_instance = 1;
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.5', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('icropper');
        $this->description = $this->l('Module for Cropping Images');

        $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall?');

        if (!Configuration::get('MYMODULE_NAME'))
            $this->warning = $this->l('No name provided');
    }

    public function install()
    {
        $filename = _PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/override/cropp.php';
        $ext = get_loaded_extensions();
        foreach($ext as $i)
        {
            if($i == "imagick") {
                $imgck = $i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!parent::install()) {
            return false;
        } elseif (!$imgck) {
            $this->context->controller->errors[] = $this->l('In your server does not installed Imagick library');
            return false;
        } elseif(file_exists($filename)) {
            $this->context->controller->errors[] = $this->l('File that override cropping 
            already exist, please delete it and replace file by yourself');
            return false;
        }else {
            //copy(__DIR__ . '/override/list_footer.tpl', _PS_ROOT_DIR_ . '/override/helpers/admin/templates/list');
        return true;
        }

    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
        if (!parent::uninstall())
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->DisplayForm();
    }

    public function displayForm(){
        $fields_formm[0] = array(
            'form' => array(
                'legend' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Header'),
                    'icon' => 'icon-file-text'
                ),
                'input' => array(
                    array(
                        'type' => '',
                        'name'=> 'vania',
                        'min'=>0,
                        'max'=>100,
                        'step'=>1
                    ),
                    'submit' => array(
                        'title' => $this->l('Generate')
                    )

                )
            )
        );

        $helper = new HelperForm();
        $helper->show_toolbar = false;
        $helper->table = $this->table;
        $lang = new Language((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'));
        $helper->default_form_language = 1;


        $this->fields_formm = array();
        $helper->submit_action = 'submitform';
        return $helper->generateForm(array($fields_formm[0]));
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Any more info? Codes, examples, errors?

Comment: If you find any in other modules like product, category etc, then copy it. But I'm pretty sure they don't exist. You'll have to include the right JS plugin for that.

Comment: Which version of prestashop are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to extends the view of the helper form. I will try to guide you :).

First, your module had to be hooked on this hook 'displayBackOfficeHeader':

```
public function install(){
    [...]
    $this->registerHook('backOfficeHeader');
    [...]
}
```

So edit your code to add this line of code.

Second step, add the function for the hook, and load, query and jquery ui for the slider

```
public function hookBackOfficeHeader($params){
    if ( Tools::getValue('module_name') == $this->name OR Tools::getValue('configure') == $this->name ) {
        $this->context->controller->addJquery();
        $this->context->controller->addJqueryUI('ui.slider');
    }
}
```

Third step, add a 'new' type to your input in the fields_form array, like `rangeslider`, and I'll suggest you to use this corrected lines of codes:

```
public function displayForm(){
    $fields_form = array(
        'form' => array(
            'legend' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Header'),
                'icon' => 'icon-file-text'
            ),
            'input' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'rangeslider',
                    'name'=> 'vania',
                    'label' => $this->l('Select range'),
                    'min'=>0,
                    'max'=>100,
                    'step'=>1
                ),
            ),
            'submit' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Generate')
            )
        )
    );

    $helper = new HelperForm();
    $helper->show_toolbar = false;
    $lang = new Language((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'));
    $helper->module                   = $this;
    $helper->default_form_language    = $this->context->language->id;

    $helper->currentIndex  = $this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminModules', false)
                             . '&configure=' . $this->name . '&tab_module=' . $this->tab . '&module_name=' . $this->name;
    $helper->token         = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');

    $helper->submit_action = 'submitform';
    return $helper->generateForm(array($fields_form));
}
```

Fourth step, add a file name `form.tpl` in this directory:
`icropper/views/templates/admin/_configure/helpers/form/form.tpl`

with this content:

```
{extends file="helpers/form/form.tpl"}
{block name="field"}
    {if $input.type == 'rangeslider'}
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            <div id="slider-range"></div>
            <p>
                <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
                <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
            </p>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        {literal}
            $( function() {
                $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
                     range: true,
                     min: {/literal}{$input.min|intval}{literal},
                     max: {/literal}{$input.max|intval}{literal},
                     step: {/literal}{$input.step|intval}{literal},
                     slide: function( event, ui ) {
                         $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
                     }
                });
                $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
                    " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
            });
        {/literal}
        </script>
    {else}
        {$smarty.block.parent}
    {/if}
{/block}
```

Here you are, this is the way to add your range slider to the form (or other input types ), by the way, in this case I have merged smarty and javascript code for quickness, but if we want to respect the prestashop mvc we have to made a different js files with slider initialization, too long to explain XD.
Cheers ;).

Tell me if I've missed something :).

Comment: wow, I'd never done it by myself, so much new info, thanks alot, you are my rescuer, but all i need is a simple slider for images quality, so I pick min 1 max 100, and giv this value to my cropper

Comment: I see, maybe you can resolve with two simple text input :)